# How do I add a CommentPart to a cell using docx4j?

Tags: xlsx, docx4j

I'm new to using docx4j and I'm trying to get a feel on reverse-engineering an XLSX document. I'm trying to add a comment to a sheet in cell A1, and I played with the online code generator and got the work in progress below. I have a method that generates the CTComments but I think I need to turn it into a CommentPart? And what method on what object do I invoke to add the CommentPart?

```
import javax.xml.bind.JAXBException;

import org.docx4j.XmlUtils;
import org.docx4j.openpackaging.packages.SpreadsheetMLPackage;
import org.docx4j.openpackaging.parts.PartName;
import org.docx4j.openpackaging.parts.SpreadsheetML.CommentsPart;
import org.docx4j.openpackaging.parts.SpreadsheetML.WorksheetPart;
import org.xlsx4j.jaxb.Context;
import org.xlsx4j.sml.CTComments;
import org.xlsx4j.sml.CTRst;
import org.xlsx4j.sml.CTXstringWhitespace;
import org.xlsx4j.sml.Cell;
import org.xlsx4j.sml.Row;
import org.xlsx4j.sml.STCellType;
import org.xlsx4j.sml.SheetData;

public class launch {

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        try { 

            String outputfilepath = "C:\\temp\\OUT_CreateSimpleSpreadsheet.xlsx";

            SpreadsheetMLPackage pkg = SpreadsheetMLPackage.createPackage();

            WorksheetPart sheet = pkg.createWorksheetPart(new PartName("/xl/worksheets/sheet1.xml"), "Sheet1", 1);
            addContent(sheet);

            pkg.save(new File(outputfilepath));

            System.out.println("\n\n done .. " + outputfilepath);   

        } catch (Exception e) { 
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private static void addContent(WorksheetPart sheet) {

        // Minimal content already present
        SheetData sheetData = sheet.getJaxbElement().getSheetData();

        // Now add
        Row row = Context.getsmlObjectFactory().createRow();
        Cell cell = Context.getsmlObjectFactory().createCell();
        cell.setV("1234");
        row.getC().add(cell);


        row.getC().add(createCell("hello world!"));
        //HOW DO I ADD A COMMENT TO THIS CELL?
        sheetData.getRow().add(row);

    }

    private static Cell createCell(String content) {

        Cell cell = Context.getsmlObjectFactory().createCell();

        CTXstringWhitespace ctx = Context.getsmlObjectFactory().createCTXstringWhitespace();
        ctx.setValue(content);

        CTRst ctrst = new CTRst();
        ctrst.setT(ctx);

        cell.setT(STCellType.INLINE_STR);
        cell.setIs(ctrst); // add ctrst as inline string

        return cell;

    }

    public static CTComments createComment() throws JAXBException { 
        String openXML = "<comments>"
                + "<authors>"
                    + "<author>Author</author>"
                +"</authors>"
                + "<commentList>"
                    + "<comment authorId=\"0\" ref=\"A1\">"
                        + "<text>"
                            + "<r>"
                                + "<rPr>"
                                    + "<b/>"
                                    + "<sz val=\"9\"/>"
                                    + "<color indexed=\"81\"/>"
                                    + "<rFont val=\"Tahoma\"/>"
                                    + "<charset val=\"1\"/>"
                                +"</rPr>"
                                + "<t>Thomas: hello world!</t>"
                            +"</r>"
                        +"</text>"
                    +"</comment>"
                +"</commentList>"
            +"</comments>";
    CTComments comments = (CTComments)XmlUtils.unmarshalString(openXML);
    return comments;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah, you are on the right track.

I've fleshed out your code and commited a complete example at [samples/XlsxAddComment.java](https://github.com/plutext/docx4j/blob/master/src/samples/xlsx4j/org/xlsx4j/samples/XlsxAddComment.java)

You'll see there how to add the CommentsPart.

A VMLPart is also required; with a  element for each comment.  In it, the x:Row and x:Column values must correspond to a comment/@ref.  For example row 0, col 0 = ref A1.